# Stuck on preparing for installation windows 10

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

My Windows 10 update is getting stuck for me today at this point
[image]

It’s unclear if this is due to demand today, or thanks to other bugs. The list of problems related to Windows 10 getting stuck within tweets is never-ending and more are arriving every couple of minutes.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can stop the download, download the .ISO, then upgrade that way.  Of course you could also way and allow that preparation phase finish.

Comment: Check task manager or performance monitor; Is there actually a process in the background doing something?  What process is it?

Comment: its downloading driver update too and trying to install them

Comment: Based on the command line for the installation process `"C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\SetupHost.Exe" /Install /Update /Quiet /ProcessId 9012 /InstallFile "C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\Install.esd"` and in my network traffic, it appear that the installer is downloading updates before the actual installation.

Comment: In my case something very silly happened. There was a license accept dialog which pops up in the background waiting for me to hit "Accept". The  upgrade bar is stuck there until I do so

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the first time when i tried to download windows 10 through windows update, it looks for me like it stucks at **preparing for installation...** So i stopped the process, restart my windows 8.1 and re-download windows 10. Samething happened for the second time, but i have waited for about 30 minutes and i have noticed that the progress bar of **preparing for installation...** continued to progress very very slowly and when it reached a specific point of the progress bar it suddenly finished the "**preparing for installation...**" phase and jumped to the upgrade phase.

I do not really know why it progresses very slowly (maybe a background task), but I found that the best solution is to wait for a big amount of time until every thing is done.

Comment: If that's truly "downloading" you have 2.7GB of installation software to move. Gonna take some time.

Comment: I'm impatient as well. It should be much faster for me with 4 SSDs in RAID 10 but its taking foreverrrrrrrrrrrr.

Comment: Can you define "big amount of time", please?

Comment: The first time I didn't time it, but it seemed to take a few hours before I cancelled it. This morning it took about an hour before it showed the licence agreement, so 'just wait longer' seems to be the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use the Windows Media Creation Tool instead.

[**[de-de]** Internetseite Deutsche](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/software-download/windows10)

[**[en-us]** English download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)

Comment: Thanks, can you use this to do free 8.1 to 10 upgrade?